# For loop through each row of a column in R

Tags: function, for-loop

I want to create a function. It should calculate how long does it take to double your investement in t=0, depending on the interest rate your investment gives.For this reason, I have created a sequence from 1% to 50%, growing by 1%. How can I implement a foor loop into my function, so that I get the results for each interest rate in my sequence?

r <- seq(from=0.01, to=0.5, by=0.01 ), myfunction <- function(r){ for (i in r) t <- log(2)/log(1+r), print (t)}

So at the end, I want to have a new variable/column where I can see t for each  interest rate in the sequence